Cant ping or ssh ubuntu server locally, server can ping websites
Installed ubuntu server and openssh on old laptop installation went well. Settings good, all firewalls down, ssh active BUT still no machine can ping server n server can ping machines. Tried pinging ip4 with phones and tabs same result. Pings and ssh verbose usually timeout.
On running traceroute to devices no results just empty rows. All machines on same subnet and DNS.
Im out of ideas please help.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
